# Sed capitalize every word on specific lines

Tags: sed, capitalize

I have markdown files formated like

```
chapter one
Blah, blah, blah.
chapter one-hundred-fifty-three
```

And also files formatted like

```
CHAPTER ONE
Blah, blah, blah.
CHAPTER ONE-HUNDRED-FIFTY-THREE
```

In both cases I want to capitalize the chapter lines to say

```
# Chapter One
Blah, blah, blah.
# Chapter One-Hundred-Fifty-Three
```

I want to use sed (or awk or possibly some other linux cli program that pipes input and output)

I've found solutions to cap every word in a file but I'm not sure how to restrict it to specific lines or how to include words-connected-with-dashes-instead-of-whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`, use an address (indicating the target line number) to tell it to apply the substitution to the desired line. For example to apply the substitution to the first line:

```
sed -r '1s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g' file
```

To apply the substitution to the third line:

```
sed -r '3s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g' file
```

To apply the substitution to both the first and third lines:

```
sed -r -e '1s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g' -e '3s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g'
```

If you don't mind the second line being modified, you can use an address range:

```
sed -r '1,3s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g'
```

***EDIT:***

As per comments below:

```
sed -r '/^chapter/I { s/^/# /; s/(\w)(\w*)/\U\1\L\2/g }' file
```

Results:

```
# Chapter One
Blah, blah, blah.
# Chapter One-Hundred-Fifty-Three
# Chapter One
Blah, blah, blah.
# Chapter One-Hundred-Fifty-Three
```

Comment: As these are huge files (books) I don't know which lines they will be on. All I have is "^chapter" to go on

Comment: @roguesith, steve has given you the correct answer. Please reward him by accepting his answer. Also, this code uses GNU extensions, so let us know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @roguesith: You can use a pattern as an address to tell `sed` which lines to make the substitutions. HTH. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like that in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) {
  if(/^chapter/i) {
    $_ = join " ", map ucfirst, split / /, lc;
    $_ = join "-", map ucfirst, split /-/;
  }
  print;
}
```

Call this like e.g. `perl script < input-text > capitalized-text`. My Perl-fu is a but rusty, I'm sure somebody will fold this into a oneliner called as an argument.